# Is anyone using delimited continuations to do web development in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, delimited-continuations

Is anyone using delimited continuations for Haskell development, specifically web development? I find the topic fascinating I need something more accessible than what I've been studying.

Here are the resources I've found so far:

- [Shift To Control](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/recur/recur.pdf)
- [The Haskell Wiki Page on Delimited Continuations](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Library/CC-delcont#Delimited_continuations)
- [A Monadic Framework for Delimited Continuations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.72.8645&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [The Delimited Continuations topic on Oleg's page](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/index.html)

Thanks!

-deech

Comment: +1 I'm currently studying the same topic, although on a different platform

Comment: Vote to close: not really a SO question. It's a cool topic, though. Open-ended discussion on mailing lists, irc, or /r/haskell would be better.

Comment: @Dan: I think reference requests (either for papers or libraries) are excellent SO questions, especially since SO's wikilike nature means that a question can be updated as new material is found or becomes available.

Comment: @sclv Maybe because of this, CW is needed.

Comment: @Dan: Er, but... it *is* a real question and it's quite clear what's being asked. I think what you wanted was "off topic". Although, I'm not really convinced that it is.

Answer (score 7):

The neatest stuff that I know of regarding web servers and delimited continuations and such is going on in Racket -- see these papers from Jay A. McCarthy:

http://faculty.cs.byu.edu/~jay/static/oopsla026-mccarthy.pdf

http://faculty.cs.byu.edu/~jay/static/icfp065-mccarthy.pdf

Answer (score 5):

No, I don't think so. I'm not aware of any work in Haskell on this, and Hackage shows up nothing web-related using [CC-delcont](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/CC-delcont).

You're breaking new ground.

Answer (score 3):

Googling "partial continuations" yields more promising results:

Partial continuations in:

- Scheme [1]
- Smalltalk [2]
- Scala [3]
- Java [4]

[1] http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/scheme/partial-continuations.html

[2] http://blog.fitzell.ca/2009/01/seaside-partial-continuations.html

[3] http://www.scribd.com/doc/39773630/ScalaFlow-Continuation-based-Data-Flow-in-Scala

[4] http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/continuations.html